# Use a covariate transformation in CreateTableOne() function (tableone package)

Tags: r, regression, spline

I am using IPTW analysis following [this great tutorial](https://rpubs.com/sar03/642530) on some data. I am using restricted cubic splines in my data with [rms::rcs()](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rms/html/rms.trans.html) function. I was wondering if there is a way to use `rcs()` transformation for a variable inside [CreateTableOne()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tableone/versions/0.13.2/topics/CreateTableOne) function.

If I try to use it:

```
Unadjusted <- CreateTableOne( data = DB1, vars = c(COVARIATES, 'rcs(ONSET,4)'), strata = 'ASM_USED')
```

it drops as it obviously does not find the column:

> Warning message: In ModuleReturnVarsExist(vars, data) : The data frame
> does not have: rcs(ONSET,4) Dropped

Is there any way to put this `rcs()` transformation for a variable inside `CreateTableOne()`?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Answer (score -2):

The rcs() function from the rms package is used to transform a continuous variable into restricted cubic splines. However, CreateTableOne() function from the tableone package does not support such transformations directly.

One possible workaround is to create the restricted cubic spline transformation outside the CreateTableOne() function and include the transformed variable as a new column in the input data frame. Then, you can specify the new variable name in the vars argument of CreateTableOne().

As you didn't provide code, Here's an example code:

```
library(tableone)
library(rms)

# Create restricted cubic spline transformation of ONSET variable
DB1$ONSET_rcs <- rcs(DB1$ONSET, 4)

# Specify the new variable name in the CreateTableOne() function
Unadjusted <- CreateTableOne(data = DB1, 
                              vars = c(COVARIATES, 'ONSET_rcs'), 
                              strata = 'ASM_USED')
```

This should create a table of summary statistics for the transformed ONSET variable using restricted cubic splines.

Comment: The transformation creates multiple columns and `CreateTableOne` is unable to interpret it then: ```In CreateTableOne(data = DB1, vars = COVARIATES, strata = "ASM_USED") :
  Dropping variable(s) ONSET_rcs  due to unsupported class.```